# Will the Job Manager be the bottleneck of Flink when running lots of jobs?

Tags: apache-flink

I've heard that Flink Job Manager is something similar to Spark Driver, in Spark, for different job, it can use different Driver node.

While for Flink, since there's only one Job Manager, will it be too busy when there're too many jobs submitted?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run Flink on a resource manager (Yarn, Mesos, Kubernetes), you can easily run Flink with one JobManager per job.